# I am trying to scrape data from this site, and while the code works for the first few pages, it elicits errors when I loop over all the pages I need

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Heres is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.census.nationalarchives.ie/search/results.jsp?census_year=1911&surname=&exact=&firstname=&county19011911=&county1821=&county1831=&county1841=&county1851=&townland=&ded=&age=&sex=&relationToHead=&religion=&education=&occupation=&marriageStatus=&marriageYears=&childrenBorn=&childrenLiving=&birthplace=&language=&deafdumb=&search=Search&sort=&pageSize=100&houseNumber=&familiesNumber=&malesNumber=&femalesNumber=&maleServNumber=&femaleServNumber=&estChurchNumber=&romanCatNumber=&presbNumberDiv=&protNumber=&parish=&barony=&yearsMarried=&causeOfDeath=&yearOfDeath=&familyId=&ageInMonths=&pager.offset=100"

res = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(res.text)
og_table = table[0]
#The above returns a pandas DataFrame

#Now, I loop through each page and append to the original DataFrame
for i in range(100, 4384418, 100):
    try:
        url = "http://www.census.nationalarchives.ie/search/results.jsp?census_year=1911&surname=&exact=&firstname=&county19011911=&county1821=&county1831=&county1841=&county1851=&townland=&ded=&age=&sex=&relationToHead=&religion=&education=&occupation=&marriageStatus=&marriageYears=&childrenBorn=&childrenLiving=&birthplace=&language=&deafdumb=&search=Search&sort=&pageSize=100&houseNumber=&familiesNumber=&malesNumber=&femalesNumber=&maleServNumber=&femaleServNumber=&estChurchNumber=&romanCatNumber=&presbNumberDiv=&protNumber=&parish=&barony=&yearsMarried=&causeOfDeath=&yearOfDeath=&familyId=&ageInMonths=&pager.offset={}".format(i)
        res = requests.get(url)
        tables = pd.read_html(res.text)
        og_table = og_table.append(tables[0])
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout Error")

og_table.to_excel("irish_output_1911.xlsx")
```

### #The loop works up to range(100, 5000, 100)

And here is the error:

> "ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.census.nationalarchives.ie', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)"

Comment: There are two solutions.If you don't want just get it online, you can read all from all pages and save them in text files. At the end you can change your code any append them to your 'og_table' smoothly from your hard disk. Otherwise you should trace and see exactly in which page you get timeout. Does this happen in that page when you call it alone or when call all bulk pages? Does it happen in same page or different pages? These are important questions you have to notice. Good luck

Comment: this range(100, 6200, 100) worked fine for me. sorry, couldn't reproduce your error.

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeon, it works up to the mid thousands. I tried 5,000,000, however, and it didn't work, giving the above error.